# Django static files (404 not found) - Openshift

Tags: python, django, static, openshift, static-files

I'm trying to run my very first project using Python/Django on Openshift and have problem with loading my static files.

I've read the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ multiple times I have been breaking my head over this for a full day but can't figure out the problem.

I'm running a developer server:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if 'OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR' in os.environ:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'), 'wsgi', 'static')
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(WSGI_DIR, 'static')
```

template

```
{% load static %}
<a href=""><img src="{% static "logo2.png" %}"></a>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/index/')),
    url(r'^index/', include('index.urls')),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

The weirdest thing is that after pushing my app to openshift everything is working just fine but on localhost sth goes wrong.

Make long story short:

- 127.0.0.1:8000/static/logo2.png - Not found
- mysite.rhcloud.com/static/logo.png - Yeah, I see the image

I hope it's clear and my problem is as stupid as I imagine.

Django 1.8, OS Windows

**SOLUTION:**

I've deleted the 'django.contrib.staticfiles' from INSTALLED_APPS and add to the urls.py this peace of code:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you in development mode? If yes and if you don't have  django.contrib.staticfiles in INSTALLED_APPS, you need to add this to urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
...   
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development).

Comment: Yes, I think I am in development mode (DEBUG = True) and I have django.contrib.staticfiles in INSTALLED_APPS. This peace of code doesn;t solve the problem and static files are still not found.

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to do this. When you have `DEBUG = True` Django can typically serve the static files from `STATIC_URL` without needing to add anything to the `urlpatterns`. The problem is probably that you put static files in `WSGI_DIR/static` instead of inside the app directory, which is the canonical place.

Comment: Can be because of that too, but once I had the same problem and I only fixed with this solution. If that's not a good idea, why is it in the official django documents?